# How to create a customized time-driven triggers in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to create a customized time-driven triggers with multiple parameters.

I've tried the manual creation of triggers in spreadsheet. However, it can only create a single parameter like in (minutes, hour, day, week and month) timer.
See code below:

```
 function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(5)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();
```

}

I expect to have a trigger with multiple parameters like, the script will run/triggers in a day from 1am - 5pm with 2 hours interval. I don't if this is possible. Any suggestions or ideas were much appreciated.

Comment: Try `ScriptApp.newTrigger()`

Comment: @TheMaster I've tried to use your suggestion however, it's not working. Maybe I am doing it wrong? I include it on my code.gs is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a single daily trigger for each event you want each day:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(1)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(3)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(5)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(7)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(9)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(11)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('listAll')
  .atHour(13)
  .nearMinutes(30)
  .everyDays(1) 
  .create();
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea. But when I ran the script it gives me this error: "TypeError: Cannot find function atHour in object TriggerBuilder."

Comment: oops, add .timeBased() to the trigger calls as well